# MSBuild 4.5 is ignoring project dependencies

Tags: msbuild, .net-4.5

I have a VS2010 solution file with over 20 projects in it, and some of the projects have dependencies on other projects from within the solution.

I also have multiple build configurations set up for different purposes, but I've trimmed down the projects to be built to just include the bare minimum number of projects.

For example, I have three libraries (A, B, and C), a website project, and a website deployment project (VS2010). The website has references to libraries A and B, and B in turn has a reference to C. My build configuration only has the website and the deployment project checked. When I check the project dependencies from the solution's properties, the website correctly lists the libraries, and B shows C, as expected.

When I run the build against my build config from within VS2010, it works completely fine, but when I run MSBuild on the solution specifying my configuration (as follows), it just results in a bunch of errors.

`msbuild.exe mysolution.sln /t:Build /p:configuration=MyConfig`

Here's an example of the errors I get:

`Services\IService.cs(11,63): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Priority' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I noticed this happening on my build server (TeamCity v7.1.2), but I can reproduce it on multiple machines, and I narrowed it down to an issue with MSBuild, itself.

It only started happening after I installed .NET 4.5 (and 2 security patches), so I uninstalled it, reinstalled .NET 4.0 (with patches) since it was also removed, then tried the same command, and it worked just fine.

This leads me to believe that something was changed or broken in MSBuild with .NET 4.5, but nothing in their documentation seems to talk about this kind of change.

MSBuild 4.5 documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh162058.aspx

I've even tried passing `BuildProjectDependencies=true` to MSBuild, and it comes up stating that it skipped the other projects because they were not selected in the configuration manager, which is correct and intentional.

The only way I got it to work with MSBuild 4.5 was to go back and select the projects that were being skipped, but since the actual solution is a bit more complex with the dependency chain, I don't want to have to try to manage the configurations manually each time we update the solution with new projects or dependencies. It SHOULD be automatic.

Any ideas with what I'm doing?

Answer (score 4):

If you still not resolved this issue, lets try some blind shots:

1. Msbuild have confirmed bug when it sometimes generates wrong build order based on followed dependencies. Try to build not entire solution but exact project you want to build - like `msbuild.exe YourWebsiteProject.csproj /t:Clean;Build /p:configuration=MyConfig`. Is the problem still persists ?
2. Ensure that YourWebsiteProject and your libs (B and C) have proper references - on project, not on dll in another project folder (simplest way to fix that - remove from B reference to C and re-add it again, just ensure that you are adding project reference and not browsing to bin\Debug for very C.dll). Is issue still there ?

If you could provide detailed or even diagnostic msbuild log (add to your msbuild command line following switches /ds /v:diag and then share teamcity full build log somewhere or pipe command line log to file) or some sample projects set where I can reproduce this behaviour - it could help a lot with issue resolving.

Comment: What do you mean when you say MSBuild has a confirmed bug? Is there a link to this issue in MSDN so I can track it and see if Microsoft has any guidance?

Comment: It was here 
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/586875/msbuild-4-0-incorrectly-processes-project-dependencies-specified-in-solution-file
fixed in 4.5

Answer (score 4):

I thought I'd update my previous answer, as I've spent a lot of time and effort creating my own workaround to this problem. The work around is a bit more comprehensive than simply living with the problem, but I've attempted to both eliminate the issue and insulate ourselves against future shocks like this.

MSBuild has been demoted from working with solutions, configurations or otherwise. MSBuild is just asked to compile projects in isolation. The order this happens is calculated by a Powershell script that parses ours solutions and projects to work out the best Just-In-Time build execution plan.

Key to this (and I think you might find helpful) are the following snippets:

**Identifying my solutions**

I have a list of all the solutions in my platform, and I essentially iterate over each of these.

```
$buildPlan = (
@{
    solutions = (
        @{
            name      = "DataStorage"
            namespace = "Platform.Databases"
        },
        @{
            name      = "CoreFramework"
        },
        @{
            namespace = "Platform.Server"
            name      = "Application1"
        },
        @{
            namespace = "Platform.Server"
            name      = "Application2"
        },
        @{
            namespace = "Platform.Client"
            name      = "Application1"
        }
     )
})
```

I have some logic that helps to translate this into actual physical paths, but its very bespoke to our needs, so I won't list it here. Sufficed to say, from this list, I can find the .sln file I need to parse.

***Parsing the solution file for projects***

With each solution, I read the .sln file and attempt to extract all the projects contained within that I will need to build later.

So firstly, identify all projects in my

```
$solutionContent = Get-Content $solutionFile

$buildConfigurations += Get-Content $solutionFile | Select-String  "{([a-fA-F0-9]{8}-([a-fA-F0-9]{4}-){3}[a-fA-F0-9]{12})}\.(Release.*)\|Any CPU\.Build" | % {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Name = $_.matches[0].groups[3].value.replace("Release ","");
            Guid = $_.matches[0].groups[1].value
          }

    }  | Sort-Object Name,Guid -unique
```

And then translate this into a nice list of projects that I can iterate over later.

```
$projectDefinitions = $solutionContent | 
      Select-String 'Project\(' |
        ForEach-Object {
          $projectParts = $_ -Split '[,=]' | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim('[ "{}]') };
          $configs = ($buildConfigurations | where  {$_.Guid -eq $projectParts[3]} | Select-Object Name)

          foreach ($config in $configs)
          {
              $santisiedConfig = if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($config.Name)){"Release"}else{$config.Name}
              if ($projectParts[1] -match "OurCompanyPrefix.")
              {
                  New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    Name = $projectParts[1];
                    File = $projectParts[2];
                    Guid = $projectParts[3];
                    Config =  $santisiedConfig
                  }
              }
          }
    }
```

**Load the Visual Studio project**

From my parsing of the solution file, I now have a list of projects per solution, which crucially contains the relative File Path from the solution root to find the project.

```
$projectDefinition = [xml](Get-Content $csProjectFileName)
$ns = @{ e = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" }
$references = @();
```

**1) Identifying external project references**

```
$references += Select-Xml -Xml $projectDefinition -XPath "//e:Project/e:ItemGroup/e:Reference" -Namespace $ns | % {$_.Node} | where {$_.Include -match "OurCompanyPrefix" -and $_.HintPath -notmatch "packages"}  | % {$_.Include}
```

**2) Identifying internal project references**

```
$references += Select-Xml -Xml $projectDefinition -XPath "//e:Project/e:ItemGroup/e:ProjectReference" -Namespace $ns | % { $_.Node.Name }
```

**3) Following "Post-Build" events as external references**

```
$references += Select-Xml -Xml $projectDefinition -XPath "//e:Project/e:PropertyGroup/e:PostBuildEvent" -Namespace $ns | where {(!([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Node.InnerText)))} | % {

            $postBuildEvents = $_.Node.InnerText.Split("`n")
            $projectsReferencedInPostBuildEvents = $postBuildEvents | Select-String "\(SolutionDir\)((\w|\.)*)" | % {$_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value}
            if ($projectsReferencedInPostBuildEvents -ne $null)
            {
                Write-Output $projectsReferencedInPostBuildEvents | % { $matchedProject = $_; ($releaseConfiguation | ? {$_.File -match $matchedProject}).Name }  
            }

        }
```

**And, since we're at it, get some basic output information too**

This is handy when it comes to iterating my list of projects to build, as know where to push the output, or where to find the output of a dependent.

```
$assemblyName = (Select-Xml -Xml $projectDefinition -XPath "//e:Project/e:PropertyGroup/e:AssemblyName" -Namespace $ns).Node.InnerText
$outputPath  = (Select-Xml -Xml $projectDefinition -XPath "//e:Project/e:PropertyGroup[contains(@Condition,'Release|')]/e:OutputPath" -Namespace $ns).Node.InnerText
```

***And at the end of it all***

We just need to make sure we don't have any duplicates, so I record just the distinct dependencies of this particular code project:

```
$dependendents = @();
if ($references -ne $null)
{
    $buildAction.project.dependencies += $references | where {(!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_))) -and ($_ -match "OurCompanyPrefix\.(.*)")} | % { $_.ToLower()} | Select -unique
}
```

I would hope this provides you with enough information for parsing your SLN and PROJ files. How you would choose to capture and store this information I think would depend entirely up to you.

I'm in the middle of writing quite an in-depth blog post about this, which will contain all the trimmings and framework I've eluded to above. The post isn't ready yet, but I will be linking to it from an earlier post : http://automagik.piximo.me/2013/02/just-in-time-compilation.html - Since this change by Microsoft nearly derailed this work!

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

In .NET 4.5, the default value of the [OnlyReferenceAndBuildProjectsEnabledInSolutionConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.tasks.assignprojectconfiguration.onlyreferenceandbuildprojectsenabledinsolutionconfiguration.aspx) property in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets was changed from `false` to `true`. As its name implies, this property causes MSBuild to ignore references to projects that are excluded from the build configuration.

(It's possible that Microsoft made this change in response to a [Connect bug I filed against MSBuild 4.0](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/571428/msbuild-4-0-builds-projects-even-if-they-are-excluded-from-a-solution-configuration), even though I warned them that the change breaks the build.)

The workaround is simple: Set the property back to `false` in the first `<PropertyGroup>` section of each of your projects:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <OnlyReferenceAndBuildProjectsEnabledInSolutionConfiguration>false</OnlyReferenceAndBuildProjectsEnabledInSolutionConfiguration>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: For some reason the link to my Connect bug is broken now. Bing still has a [cached version](http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=OnlyReferenceAndBuildProjectsEnabledInSolutionConfiguration&d=4756437099940543&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=gy6I4RMi2T9y-j5M_jzlnbwuu4wnvbzd).

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the exact same problem. The two work-around's I've managed to find are both unacceptable for the long term, but they do overcome the initial issue of getting old our build processes working with the new 4.5 stack.

1. Swap the project references with file references
2. Create compound build configurations

I've opted for #2, as file references mean the developers would lose out on real-time intellisense etc.

The compound configurations are simply this:

- **Release Server ->** All Server Projects
- **Release Consumer ->** "Release Server" + Client Projects

The problem seems to be, that if a project is not included in the current/active build configuration, that it will not include it as a referenced dependency. So, by adding the dependencies into the configuration, the projects will at least compile.

Both ugly, but at least it get's me out of a tight spot.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

I get the sense this issue has multiple causes.  I tried most of the solutions here.  I cannot change our build server to use a PS script so that solution was out. Nothing I could try worked.

Finally, I deleted my solution and started a new one.  The new solution worked.  After diffing the broken solution with the working solution, I found the original solution was was missing lines.  Each dependency that would not compile was missing this line:

```
{A93FB559-F0DB-4F4D-9569-E676F59D6168}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
```

Note 1: The GUID will change from dependency to dependency.

Note 2: You can find lines like this one under the "GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution" part of the solution file.

My build.proj file says build "Release" using the "Any CPU" platform.  Because MSBuild could not find this line it did not build this dependency.  This results in the "**error CS0246: The type or namespace could not be found**" message.

If you are curious, someone had set this solution to the "x86" platform (which is wrong for us).  I changed it to "Any CPU" (along with several other changes).  Visual Studio did not add the corresponding lines to the solution file.  Everything built fine in the IDE, but MSBuild started throwing errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found that MSBuild is building projects from a solution in order in which they are declared in the .sln file. So if you reorder them with text editor you can fix the order for MSBuild.